# css issue - drop-down not working correctly on iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

I have a css powered drop down menu which doesn't work properly on the iphone or ipad.

It works as I want it to on all other browsers and devices I've checked.

I've narrowed it down to the fact that I don't have the menu text (eg the word 'face') wrapped in href tags, like it does in the original version of the code. Thats what makes the difference. Wrap href tags around the word face and the drop down works OK on ipad/iphone

Obviously I could just add the href and be done but I really don't want to have to, otherwise everyone with a touch-screen, who would normally have to tap the menu text to get the dropdown to appear, will be taken to wherever the link points. Spoiling the whole point of the dropdown in the first place!

Here's the code:

```
<div id="dropMenuWrapper">
  <div id="dropMenu">
        <ul class="level1">
        <li class="submenu">Face
            <ul class="level2">
                <li class="subCatodd"><a href="">powder</a></li>
                <li class="subCateven"><a href="">cream</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The the css:

```
body {  behavior: url(includes/csshover.htc);}
div#dropMenu li a:hover, div#dropMenu li.submenu li.submenu:hover {color: #4f4f4f!important;background:#D5E88F;}


#dropMenuWrapper {
width:100%;
height:25px;
margin:0;
font-size:11px;
}

div#dropMenu {
width:750px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
z-index:1000;
position:relative;
}

div#dropMenu ul {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}

div#dropMenu li {
position: relative; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
float: left; 
line-height: 1em;
}

div#dropMenu ul.level1 {
width:750px; 
margin:0 auto; 
text-align:center;
background:#4F4F4F;
height:25px;
z-index:1000;
}

div#dropMenu li:hover {}
div#dropMenu li.submenu {}
div#dropMenu li.submenu:hover {}
div#dropMenu li a {display: block;text-decoration: none;} 
div#dropMenu>ul a {width: auto;}
div#dropMenu ul ul {position: absolute; width: 13em;display: none;}
div#dropMenu ul ul li {border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; width:13em;}
div#dropMenu li.submenu li.submenu {}
div#dropMenu ul.level1 li.submenu:hover ul.level2, 
div#dropMenu ul.level2 li.submenu:hover ul.level3,
div#dropMenu ul.level3 li.submenu:hover ul.level4,
div#dropMenu ul.level4 li.submenu:hover ul.level5 {display:block;z-index:1000;}
div#dropMenu ul.level2 {top: 2.17em; background:#4f4f4f;z-index:1000;}
div#dropMenu ul.level3, div#dropMenu ul.level4, div#dropMenu ul.level5 {top: 0; left: 13em; background:#4f4f4f}
div#dropMenu ul.level2 a {padding: 0.5em 0.25em;color: white; text-transform:none;}  /* this is text color on drop-down submenu */
div#dropMenu ul.level2 a:hover {color:#4f4f4f;}
```

And for ease a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VvT6Y/1/

Can anyone point out a way to get the dropdown working on iphone/ipad without having to make the text a link?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is using JS to capture events on the link elements not an option?  You can do feature detection to see if the device supports touch events and disable accordingly.  Alternately, you can leave the elements not a link and detect touch events to apply classes that give the dropMenu effect.

Comment: @cimmanon Hi there, thanks for the response. I really don't want to use javascript if I don't have to. I've too much already and my pages are quite slow (working on that). Can you explain the touch events, I've never heard that was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `:active` and/or `:focus` pseudo-class to every instance that uses `:hover`?

So, for example, `li.submenu:hover` becomes `li.submenu:hover, li.submenu:active`.

The `:active` pseudo-class is typically used when an element is "activated by the user." The most common example is the point on a link when the user has started the click action of a link (the "mousedown" event), but hasn't yet finished the action (the "mouseup" event).

The `:focus` pseudo-class is used when an element has the focus (can accept input). This is most obvious with form controls, but it's actually used far more often (ever see the little dotted border around links, especially if you tab through a form? That's `:focus`).

([W3C info on both.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act))

I mention both, because I'm not 100% sure which one iOS Safari would use in such an instance. I would assume `:focus`, but I've seen weirder things from browsers.

(On a side note, you shouldn't need `div#dropMenu`. IDs are supposed to be unique, so simply `#dropMenu` is plenty. If your ID is not unique on your page, you're using IDs wrong.)

**Edit** If the pseudo-classes don't work, then the only way you'll be able to handle it, currently, is with JavaScript, unfortunately. Thankfully, it's as simple as:

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

to detect the capability, which you can then use to trigger certain behaviors (add classes, etc) to emulate the effect. If you happen to already be using Modernizr, then you can use it's `Modernizr.touch` function to detect touchscreens.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply, I very much appreciate any help! I gave this a go but it didn't work unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Humm... was hoping to not have to use javascript - mostly because I know very little of it, but if it's the only way then I guess I'll have to bite the bullet and do a bit of learning. It's all a bit confusing! Not using modernizr so probably not worth using just for this? even if it did make it more simple?

Comment: @crazysarah - If you're even remotely serious about getting into front end web development (HTML/CSS), then learning JavaScript is pretty much a necessity, since, as you're finding, you'll almost inevitably have to use it for something. This question over at programmers.SE has a ton of resources for learning it, and should be good for getting you started: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38566/the-importance-of-javascript-and-the-best-way-to-learn-it

Comment: @crazysarah - And to answer your question about Modernizr - If you're not already using it, then yes, it's likely overkill, especially since you seem to only be experiencing this issue in iOS, and the raw JS solution is quite simple. You might want to look into the JS libraries you have, though, to see if they have a touch detection method. Libraries like jQuery will often handle cross browser issues for you, which will reduce your headaches.

Answer (score 4):

"To make a drop-down menu appear when someone taps on the menu button, all you need to do is add

```
onClick=”return true”
```

to the “A” tag within any list item (such as `<LI>`) that triggers a menu to pop up. This works for cascading menus as well."

from - http://blog.travelvictoria.com.au/2012/03/31/make-sure-your-websites-drop-down-menus-work-on-an-ipad/